# Qual usar: "typed array" ou DataView?

Tags: javascript

No ECMAScript 6 existe uma nova classe [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView), e ["typed arrays"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) (aparentemente suportadas no Internet Explorer 10 e 11), usados para manipular [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)'s. Qual a diferença entre `DataView` e typed arrays (`Uint16Array`, `Int32Array`, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já sabendo que `ArrayBuffer` representa dados binários na memória do navegador (uma coleção de bytes com tamanho fixo), as nomeadas "typed arrays" e o `DataView` nos permite manipular essa coleção do `ArrayBuffer`: basta ler ou modificar números sobre os bytes dessa coleção.

Além de que o `DataView` pode representar números de diferentes tipos em uma única `ArrayBuffer`, a diferença é somente como os bytes que formam cada número são ordenados na representação oferecida pela interface ([endianness](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html)). Por exemplo, vamos decompor os bytes de um número em 16 bits (2 bytes) em duas ordens diferentes (representação hexadecimal):

- (no big-endian) `01 00`
- (ou em little-endian): `00 01`

Nessas 2 ordens (as mais conhecidas), uma reversa da outra. O endianness apenas se aplica nos bytes que formam o número em sí.

O `DataView` define os bytes de um número independentemente do [endianness](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_(ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) do dispositivo/plataforma, sempre utilizando big-endian (ou "network-endianness"). É [dito](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/01/typedarray-or-dataview-understanding-byte-order/) que isso é útil por conta de transmissões da internet/rede.

Mesmo utilizando `DataView` ainda é possível aplicar o endianness atual da plataforma: basta definir o número manualmente utilizando números inteiros de 8 bits (1 byte), mas é mais fácil utilizar `Uint8Array` então.

Os números das typed arrays `Int8Array` e `Uint8Array` são os únicos que não se afetam pelo endianness, porque usam apenas 1 byte dos dados do `ArrayBuffer` para serem representados.

```js
console.log(
    `Uint8Array:
      ${new Uint8Array([ 0 ]).buffer.byteLength}`

  , `\nInt8Array:
      ${new Int8Array([ -129 ]).buffer.byteLength}`
);
```

Isso dá uma ideia básica, "se `DataView` vale mais apena do que typed arrays".

Sobre a performance eu não sei muito :|, é apenas dito que é mais eficiente gerenciar o endianness atual da plataforma (o mais rápido para ela), não deve custar muito.